# Creating object variables from string in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I have the following issue related to how can i create an Object varible from a String name.

```
var obj_product:Object              = new Object;
obj_product.product                 = producto.nombre_producto;
obj_product.products_proveedorID    = product.ID;
obj_product.productID               = product.productID;
obj_product.price                   = 0;

if ( _extra_headers.length > 0 && _extra_headers[0].length > 0)
    for (var index:int=0; index < _extra_headers.length; index++ )
        obj_product._extra_headers[index] = 0;
```

**_extra_headers** is an Array where I hold new header names in the Datagrid, so for every new name I need to create its variable within the object.

Whats should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an ActionScript programmer, but on the assumption that it's close enough to JavaScript, replace the last line with this:

```
obj_product[_extra_headers[index]] = 0
```